# I can't figure out my this script isn't working

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out why this div slideshow script isn't working:

The script:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
})
```

The html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
<img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
</div>
<div>
<img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
</div>
<div>
Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the site: http://www.pearsonaviation.com.au/new/

Comment: Have you looked in the developer console at all? You might find something very interesting!

Comment: looks fine... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LgmYm/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Helps if you load jQuery first and have no other syntax errors ;)

Comment: Can you guys please tell me how I'm loading jQuery wrong? If you look in the code I have included it?

Answer (score 0):

Look's fine man

http://jsfiddle.net/6A5QD/

don't forget your `;`. Your method chaining is...."interesting".

add some absolute CSS so you don't get that box "jump"

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:-**

You are loading `jquery.backstretch.min.js` before you load `jquery library` in your [site](http://www.pearsonaviation.com.au/new/) which is causing error in your site.As you are trying to use `jQuery object` which is not defined yet.

**check console**

[image]

**Solution**

Load jQuery library file before `jquery.backstretch.min.js`

Like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.pearsonaviation.com.au/new/modules/mod_backstretch/tmpl/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**your code with problem**

```
  <script src="/new/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/new/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/new/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- jquery.backstretch.min.js -->
  <script src="http://www.pearsonaviation.com.au/new/modules/mod_backstretch/tmpl/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
  </script>
  <style>
        .noImages{
        color:#000;
        font-size:11px;
        background:#F9EAAE;
        border:1px dotted #ff0000;
        padding:5px;
        }

        </style>

<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/new/templates/onlinespark/css/template.css" />


you are loading jQuery.min here
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/new/templates/onlinespark/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script src="/new/templates/onlinespark/HelveticaNeueLT_Com_65_Md_800.font.js"></script>
```